# Second Absolute moment of a stochastic process in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $(X(t))_{t\in[0,1]}$ be a stochastic process with trajectories in $L^2[0,1]$ and continuous covariance function k(s,t). I need to show that the second absolute moment is finite, i.e. $\mathbb{E}\|X\|^2< \infty$.

This is my approach:

If $k(s,t):=\mathbb{E}[X(s)X(t)]$, then $k(t,t)=\mathbb{E}[X(t)^2]$

on the other hand, the second absolute moment is given by: $\mathbb{E}\|X\|^2=\int_{0}^{1} |X(t)|^2dP(x)$

In all places $\mathbb{E}$ denotes Bochner expectation (or strong expatation). So I am not sure how to conclude relating $k(t,t)$ and $\mathbb{E}\|X\|^2$ in the case of this expectation.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Well, if i am not wrong, you can show by Ito's isometry that $\mathbb{E}[(\int_0^1 X_t dW_t)^2]=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^1 (X_t^2) dt]$ since $(X_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ is a square integrable function (belongs to $\mathbb{L}^2([0,1])$...

Comment: I think I need to use some machinery concerning Mercer's theorem or Karuhnen Loeve expansion, nothing related with Ito's integration, even you could be right, but honestly, I don't know.

Comment: Ok, i see! But, is this from some course in financial mathematics?

Comment: In Mathematical statistics, namely in Functional Data Analysis.